# RVM Bundle Install Missing Gem Error even though gem is installed

Tags: rubygems, rvm, bundler

I'm getting the following error even though I currently do have the Bundler gem installed (it appears when I run $gem list).

```
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
```

I'm using RVM and my $PATH is as follows:

```
/Users/cjstingl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin:
/Users/cjstingl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:
/Users/cjstingl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:
/Users/cjstingl/.rvm/bin:
/Users/cjstingl/.bin:
/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/Cellar/php/5.3.6/bin:
/usr/local/share/python:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/X11/bin
```

Also this is my gem env

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/cjstingl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial2ndEd
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/cjstingl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/cjstingl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/cjstingl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial2ndEd
     - /Users/cjstingl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => false
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "-n/usr/local/bin --no-ri --no-rdoc --no-user-install"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Also: Using the bundle -v command returns the same error

I've tried imploding RVM and reinstalling which doesn't seem to work. I'm stumped and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use the `bundle` command? Try `bundle -v`

Comment: Using the bundle -v command returns the same error

Comment: Strange, the `bundle` command is part of the Bundler gem - if the command runs (even giving an error message) that means Ruby is loading somehow. You've made sure that you ran `gem install bundler`?

Answer (score 94):

Adding the following (taken from .bash_profile) to .bashrc fixed it for me:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: Don't forget to run `source .bashrc` from your home directory.

Comment: @Roman I'm running into this problem after a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 and using RVM. Why is this happening?! Shouldn't RVM set these paths up properly itself?

Comment: Worked for me running zsh and oh-my-zsh on Mountain Lion.

Comment: if this doesn't work you may not be logged in properly. eg. you didn't su - username

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem with a clean install of RVM 1.10.3.  After reinstalling I noticed that bundler is installed, and that <gemset>/bin directories are being added to my $PATH, but those bin directories don't actually exist.   I think it's just an RVM bug.

As a quick fix I manually copied the `bundle` binary into an RVM bin dir that does exist.  That seems to have fixed my problem:

```
$ cd ~/.rvm
$ cp gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.21/bin/bundle rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/
```

The Ruby and Bundler versions in those paths will likely be different for you.

---

The solution above works however it was bugging me so I put it to the rvm guys; it turns out my ~/.gemrc file was overriding the gem location with this line:

```
- "gem" => "-n/usr/local/bin"
```

Removing it fixed it for me.  See here for full thread: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1043#issuecomment-7336267

Comment: Worked for me. `ln -s ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fonista/bin/bundle ~/.rvm/bin/` did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I had an error that was resolved by removing the "gem: /usr/local/bin" in my .gemrc. Thanks!

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Too many gem names (/usr/local/bin, /usr/local/bin); please specify only one

Comment: T_T I spent 3hrs coz this issue... Thank u!!! Also good to check this too https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1043

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem, and the answer (at least for me) was maddeningly simple after lots of trial and error.

This is definitely a path issue, and @gamecreature's mentioning of path order was the crucial clue for me.

I'm not sure how it happened, but I had `$HOME/.rvm/bin` as the first item in my PATH export.

This is unnecessary as this directory gets added to the path in the correct order through sourcing the rvm file.

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

So my fix was just to remove `$HOME/.rvm/bin` from my PATH export.

If you have multiple init files (.bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile), make sure to follow the advice on the [rvm troubleshooting page](http://rvm.overnothing.com/troubleshooting/):

> make sure that the sourcing of the rvm file occurs *last* in your
>   profile files (.bash_profile / .bashrc / .zshrc) essentially after any
>   customizations of PATH / functions or aliases.

But I'd also recommend checking the rest of your PATH definition to make sure there aren't any duplicates declared that would take precedence.

Comment: This fixed my problem, I have installed rvm a number of times now, and must have gotten lazy and skipped this step (adding [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" to my .bashrc file.) This also resolved some other weird behavior. Thanks for giving a good answer, and explaining yourself.

Comment: @Patrick Smith: Very good tip about the multiple init files!  This has bitten me in a couple instances ;-)

It appears the [RVM troubleshooting link has changed to this location](https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting/).  I would also recommend to direct users to the [Invocation section of the bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash). It really helps to de-mystify shell behavior in the case of login vs. non-login shells,  the priority order of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, & `~/.profile` files, and finally the posix mode and historical `sh` modes.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue. It turned out I didn't have a project specific .rvmrc file. I just created it using

```
rvm --rvmrc --create 1.9.3@my_project_name
```

In my project dir

This solved the issue

Comment: This solved my issue as well. Does this mean one has to do this on every project? I didn't use to do this...

Comment: I swiched to rbenv. It is much simpler and does not have a concept of gemsets. If you use bundler in all apps, rbenv is a nobrainer.

Answer (score 6):

*If you got to the bottom of this and are still banging your head against the wall...*

My problem was that `rvm install 1.8.7` failed late in the install but appeared to have been successful (I had ruby 1.8.7 and could create gemsets)

But it seems like `$GEM_HOME` is set late in the install script and since that wasn't set, rvm wasn't looking in the right spot for gems.

I ran `rvm reinstall 1.8.7` and looked carefully for errors.

What tipped me off was this thread:
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rubyversionmanager/aUBDxbBzZpE/discussion

You can check to see if this is your problem by running

`echo $GEM_HOME` or `gem env` or checking your rvm install log (see link above)

Do you see your ruby version and gemset name in your Gem Path?  If not, maybe the rvm install failed.

Comment: I'd +1 this post a few more times if I could. The final clue was that $GEM_HOME was showing the correct path for my current rvm Ruby version, but `gem env` Gem paths were showing paths for the default Ruby version. I attempted `rvm reinstall 1.9.2-p180` and spotted an error while installing rubygems that said I needed to add `--verify-downloads 1` to the command. IT WORKED. /headbanging

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's the cause of your problem.
But I had a similar problem. The reason was that my RVM environment wasn't correctly.

I had 2 users, one which was working one that didn't.
The working user used the following bundle script. (output from: which bundle)

`/home/rvm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/bundle`

The wrong rvm-installation user used:

`/home/user/.rvm/bin/bundle`

The reason for this is the wrong $PATH order. The .rvm/gems/ruby-.../bin path should be placed before the ./rvm/bin path.

In my situation the cause was I set the $PATH variable to a rvm of another user. I fixed the issue by adding a symbolic link to the RVM of the user and changing my path from:

`/home/rvm/.rvm/bin`

to

`/home/user/.rvm/bin`

When the code above does not work for you, you can manually adjust the path just AFTER loading rvm.

Answer (score 4):

Try this : https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/

it says about profiles run on startup, i am running ubuntu 12.10 and it work. Only thing you have to do is set "Run command as a login shell" in terminal profile preferences (tab title and command).

Hope it saves some time to someone.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me as well after switching to a new empty gemset and running `gem install bundler`. The cause is that the shell is "remembering" the last `bundle` executable you used. To fix that (at least in `bash`-descendants):

```
hash -r
```

Answer (score 3):

You know what, this is obviously your PATH variable's problem.

You should make sure that `which bundle` to be like `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/bundle` instead of something like `/usr/local/rvm/bin/bundle`.

hint:

Did you just use PATH=some explicit list in your .zshrc file?

Then you should change that to PATH=$PATH:some list

Answer (score 3):

After having RVM installed on multiple machines with the same setup and having problems with RVM on one but not having these problems on another one, I decided to look for something better, less error prone.

I found and switched to **[rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#readme)**, which is much more simplistic than RVM.

And as the `README` of rbenv states:

> ## rbenv does…
>
> - Let you **change the global Ruby version** on a per-user basis.
> - Provide support for **per-project Ruby versions**.
> - Allow you to **override the Ruby version** with an environment variable.
>
> ## In contrast with rvm, rbenv does not…
>
> - **Need to be loaded into your shell.** Instead, rbenv's shim approach works by adding a directory to your $PATH.
> - **Override shell commands like cd.** That's dangerous and error-prone.
> - **Have a configuration file.** There's nothing to configure except which version of Ruby you want to use.
> - **Install Ruby.** You can build and install Ruby yourself, or use [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) to automate the process.
> - **Manage gemsets.** [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) is a better way to manage application dependencies. If you have projects that are not yet using Bundler you can install the [rbenv-gemset](https://github.com/jamis/rbenv-gemset) plugin.
> - **Require changes to Ruby libraries for compatibility.** The simplicity of rbenv means as long as it's in your $PATH, [nothing else](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/bundler/) needs to know about it.
> - **Prompt you with warnings when you switch to a project.** Instead of executing arbitrary code, rbenv reads just the version name from each project. There's nothing to "trust."

So if you ask me, dump RVM and switch to rbenv.

Answer (score 2):

I installed ruby 1.9.3 by rvm. After git octopress completed, just edit $path_of_git/.rvmrc like this "rvm use 1.9.3". AND THEN run command of "cd ..; cd $path_of_git". After that it will ask you weather trust the .rvmrc or not. Type 'y' to make .rvmrc file work.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem for a slightly different reason. My home directory had a `.gemrc` file left over from an old ruby setup, and I'd missed when deleting the old files. It seems that gem was confusing the rvm settings with the settings in this file. Once I removed it (and some files installed to the old location), everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem earlier today.  The approach I used to resolve the issue was this:

1) Run

```
cap shell
```

on the same machine you would normally run cap deploy.  Then execute

```
env | sort
```

This runs the command on the remote server.  Copy and paste the  output into a local text file, e.g. capenv.txt

2) SSH into the same remote server, and do the same command, namely env | sort.  Save this locally as a text file, e.g. sshenv.txt

3) Diff the two files and see what is in sshenv.txt that is not in capenv.txt - this is most  likely where your problem lies.

```
< ++CAP ++
< _=/bin/sh
---
> ++ SSH ++
> __array_start=0
14a15
> PS1=\[\e]2;tracker@charlotte\a\e[0;31m LIVE:\u@\h \w> \e[0m
18d18
< rvm_env_string=ruby-1.9.3-p194
21d20
< rvm_ruby_string=ruby-1.9.3-p194
27c26,28
< USER=tracker
\ No newline at end of file
---
> USER=tracker
> USES_BASHRC=bashrc
> _=/usr/bin/env
```

4) I immediately noticed that the shell interpreter was not set to bash.  This can be fixed by adding

```
set :shell, '/usr/bin/bash'
```

to your deploy.rb file.  This resolved my problem

Comment: Also you can do 'ruby -v' in the capistrano shell.  If the wrong version shows up then that will indicate why bundler is not working

Answer (score 1):

This works for me when I specify the version of Ruby I want to use:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.2-p290
Using /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this problem myself after updating my Ruby patch level.  I ran `which gem` and discovered that it was using a global version of rubygems, in this case the path was `~/.rvm/bin/gem`.  So I ran `rvm rubygems current`, which installed it in `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p370/bin/gem`.  Ran `gem install bundler` and `bundle` again.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I had an empty `.rvmrc` file in the directory I switched to (rvm 1.15.1). Obviously there are lots of causes for this error

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue (where I kept on installing the bundler and rvm won't recognize it) on one of my laptops.  I guessed I might have installed RVM wrong while I was still a rails noob.  I tried the solution above but it didn't work for me.  After messing around with it, I gave up and removed RVM and reinstall it.  I figured it was due to some weird configuration issue deeply nested somewhere or .  Here are the steps I took:

Remove RVM:

```
rvm implode
```

Install RVM again:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
rvm reload
```

Since I am working on an old rails project for work, I had to install ree-1.8.7-2012.02

```
rvm install ree-1.8.7-2012.02
```

Of course, Murphy's Law still applies.  I ran into another issue where my laptop could not find a **Non-broken C compiler** even though Xcode is installed along with gcc.  My final steps were going to *https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer* and install their package and reinstalling ree.

I hope this last resort solution helps someone.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For my setup, adding the user that apache runs as to the rvm group worked

```
usermod -a -G rvm www-data
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, too.  I fixed my issue by specifying a gemset.

```
$ bundle install
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.

$ rvm gemdir
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194

$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p194 (found in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194)
   global
   rails32

$ rvm gemset use rails32

Using ruby-1.9.3-p194 with gemset rails32

$ rails s

Could not find rake-10.0.4 in any of the sources

Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

$ bundle install

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
{And voila! it worked!}
```