# Ruby: "gem install bundler" not installing bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I'm new to rails and trying to get a demo app up and running.  I've been having problems on my linux system (lubuntu, mostly clean install) getting "bundle install" to run.  Even when it does, if I close my terminal and start another, it fails to run again.  The cycle looks something like this:

```
sandbox@75bf7f3:~/railsstuff/sample_app_2nd_ed$ bundle install
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.

sandbox@75bf7f3:~/railsstuff/sample_app_2nd_ed$ gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.1.4
1 gem installed

sandbox@75bf7f3:~/railsstuff/sample_app_2nd_ed$ bundle install
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
```

As far as I can tell, I'm using the latest version of Ruby and rvm seems to be working fine.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Did you create a new gemset with rvm?  Are you switching to that gemset via 'rvm use' when you open a new terminal?

Comment: "rvm use 1.9.3 --default" fixes it when I run it in a new terminal.

Comment: yes, but to use a specific gemset you would do something like "rvm use 1.9.2@rails32"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm this is happening in a fresh rvm install of Linux Mint.  I'm using gnome-terminal and I have applied the "Run command as login shell" workaround.  I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and haven't done anything with gemsets.  When I type 'gem list' I see all the rubies I've installed (the first hour I got rvm installed, I playing around installing some projects and it seemed to be in perfect working order).

It looks like adding

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

to ~/.bashrc clears up the inconsistency problems.  It's odd that it was working fine initially without it...  And it should only be sourcing .bash_login in the first place...

Comment: I have the same problem, and hat the entry above in my .bash_profile (installed as part of the rvm installation script), but still having this issue.