# "gem install bundler" won't work with a project that includes a gemset(rvm) in Mac OS x 10.8.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, rvm

My problem is summarized in the following lines:

```
Joses-MacBook-Pro:~ jose$ cd Estate/
Using /Users/jose/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290 with gemset realstate
Joses-MacBook-Pro:Estate jose$ bundle
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
Joses-MacBook-Pro:Estate jose$ gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.2.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.2.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.2.1...
Joses-MacBook-Pro:Estate jose$ bundle
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
Joses-MacBook-Pro:Estate jose$
```

Here's the output for my Gem Env:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-darwin12.1.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jose/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/jose/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/jose/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/jose/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
     - /Users/jose/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I've tried to solve this problem by using many answers I've seen around here, like:
[Ruby: "gem install bundler" not installing bundler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296737/ruby-gem-install-bundler-not-installing-bundler)

But unfortunately so far I've not been able to solve the problem, I hope somebody can help me out figuring this out. I'm a Mac OS X newcomer.

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT:**

*which bundle:*

```
Joses-MacBook-Pro:Estate jose$ which bundle
/Users/jose/.rvm/bin/bundle
```

*$(which bundle)*

*which gem, etc*

```
Joses-MacBook-Pro:Estate jose$ which gem || type gem | head -n 1
/Users/jose/.rvm/bin/gem
Joses-MacBook-ProEstate jose$ hash -r
Joses-MacBook-Pro:Estate jose$
```

Comment: what returns `which bundle` and can you run `$(which bundle)`?

Comment: Hello there ! I've just added the output you requested to the question

Comment: This is not an answer, just a comment.  Mac OS X has been "Rails unfriendly" since 10.7 (prior to Lion, Rails was shipped pre-installed).  As such, I've given up the struggle and am in the process of migrating my servers to Linux. YMMV, so, if I was starting a Rails project now, I wouldn't start it on Mac OS X.

Comment: Ok, good to know, I've not had trouble so far with Rails, apart from rvm that is. I've been a Rails developer for over 2 years now, I've always used Ubuntu until like a month ago, when I joined a Rails shop where everyone uses Mac OSX, and having seen how cool everything was there, I was adviced to do the switch to OS X.

Comment: additional checks would be `which gem || type gem | head -n 1` and try after `hash -r`

Comment: @mpapis I've attached your request once more. hope it proves useful :) and thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to explicitly use ruby:

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

Comment: YES! that worked ! Could you please explain to me why and how did that work? thank you sir, fantastic product rvm is.

Comment: rvm should by default while installing first ruby **use** and make it **default**, not sure why this did not happen for you, maybe older rvm?

Comment: Well, I don't think so, My install is like 1 day old. I believe I used this command to fetch  RVM: curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby. version fetched was: 1.14.10 I think. thanks for your reply.

Comment: 1.14.10 is almost 2 months old, actual version is 1.15.9

Comment: but anyway, this could be issue in the `--ruby` flag to installer, maybe it can not set default ruby .. which should be done in this case.

Comment: Thanks for all your invaluable advice.