# Rails Gem bundler not installed - even after I install it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

For a Rails app, I tried running `$ bundle install`. But, even after I ran `$ gem install bundler`, I got the same message.

this is what happened:

```
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
Davids-iMac-2:213calendar davidburton$ bundle install
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
Davids-iMac-2:213calendar davidburton$ gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.3.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.3.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.3.5...
Davids-iMac-2:213calendar davidburton$ bundle install
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
```

UPDATE1

```
rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p374 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Comment: What kind of ruby environment do you have set up? Are you using rbenv, rvm or something like that? and what does "gem list" and "which ruby" print out in the console?

Comment: Which ruby = `/Users/davidburton/.rvm/bin/ruby`

Comment: gem list - lists a lot of gems.

Comment: And is the bundler gem included in the list? :)

Comment: Yes - bundler (1.3.5, 1.2.3)

Comment: Hmm that´s weird.. maybe one of the answer on this question could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990828/rvm-bundle-install-missing-gem-error-even-though-gem-is-installed

Comment: try : gem install bundler --pre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your home directory for a `~/.bash_profile` file.

If it exists, and you don't remember creating it, copy its contents to `~/.bashrc` and remove the `.bash_profile` file completely.

By default, rvm appends the commands for updating path with rvm function in `.bash_profile` after `rvm` installation.
Ubuntu, at a time only uses `.bash_profile` if it is present, or `.bashrc` when `.bash_profile` is absent. This results in `PATH` not being correctly set, and the gem, even though installed, is not detected since it is not on your path.